# Starting music in Form 1 and stopping in Form 2

Tags: c#, winforms, mute, wmplib

I'm looking to make a 'Music on/off' button in my application. I'm using the following code in `Form 1`, this is the form in which I play the music:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;

namespace WWE2K14SaveEditor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        public WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }   


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                wplayer.URL = "music/main.mp3";
                wplayer.controls.play();
            }
            catch { }    

        }
```

I want the music to stop when I press a button in `Form 2`, I've tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
frm1.wplayer.controls.stop();
```

(This code is used in the button click event.)

This is a Windows Forms application. I'm using the `WMPLib`.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
public static WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
```

then call it from Form2 with

```
Form1.wplayer.controls.stop();
```

Currently you are just instantiating new instance of Form1 in your Form2 which will have different wplayer instance than the one you have started the music.

Comment: Also note that from now on you will have only one music player instance for your windows form application so keep that in mind. If you need multiple you need to work around different solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a second instance of `Form1` which has no relation to the instance playing the music.

You need to pass a reference to the `Form1` instance which is playing the music to `Form2`, and have it call `stop()` through that instance.

Actually, you may as well pass the `WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer` instance on to `Form2`, as it will prevent `Form2` having to know anything about `Form1`.

e.g.

```
public Form2(WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer player)
{
    // Assign player to a private member variable.
    this.player = player;
}
```

Then create your second form using `new Form2(wplayer);`, and call `player.stop();` in your click handler.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but when I tried that, the IDE wouldn't show the wplayer variable as a suggestion. The answer by Janne Matikainen shows that I had to put static before my wplayer declaration. Which did the job! Thanks for the answer.
EDIT: Just read your edit, that's another way to do it. I found that Janne's way was easier, but I will most definitely keep this in mind. Who knows? I may have to use this sometime. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Raza Yeah, note that with my answer I'd move the initialization of `wplayer` and `frm2` to `Form1`'s constructor. Obviously initializing `wplayer` first, then passing it into `Form2`. The only thing I'd say about using a `public static` field (or even just `public` for that matter) is that it makes it very easy for code to get tangled. With the solution you chose, that `wplayer` variable can be accessed from *anywhere*. I suspect this isn't a problem for you with this project - I'm guessing it's just you experimenting and learning, which is cool. Just be aware it's not best practice.

Comment: +1 for the only answer (so far) that calls attention to best practice in this area.

Answer (score 0):

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
```

This creates a new instance of your form, it doesn't reference the form playing the music.

You need to pass a reference to Form1 to Form2.  One tactic could be to add a property to Form2 called MusicForm or something similar - then when you create form2 you can pass a reference to form1.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        public Form1 MusicForm { get; set;}
        ...
        ...
```

Then you can modify Form1:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.MusicForm = this;

        public WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
```

Then call:
   this.MusicForm.wplayer.controls.stop();

Of course, you don't need to pass the whole form if all if all you want to pass in the WindowsMediaPlayer instead - you could also just pass that in as a property.